# Checkbox (JSP PAGE) and insert on mysql database

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, database, jsp

i have a jsp page that user in form has to give a destination : city,country,url_of_city and 3 checkbox with the kind of the destination (summer,winter,christmas) , he can check max 2 boxes, so i need to take the results of this and insert them to a database in order to be able later to search for this destination , how can i do it this?

mysql code :

```
CREATE TABLE DEST_C(ID_DEST_C INT(5),CATEGORY VARCHAR(45))
CREATE TABLE DEST(ID1_DEST INT(6),ID2_DEST INT (6),COUNTRY VARCHAR(40),CITY VARCHAR(40),URL VARCHAR(5400));
```

jsp form code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>create dest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <html>
    <head>
        <title>CREATE DESTINATION</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> CREATING DESTINATION </h1>
        <form name="createdest" method="get" action="create dest code.jsp">
        Country: <input type="text"  required  name="id8" /> <br>
        City: <input type="text"  required  name="id9" /> <br>
        URL Video: <input type="url"  required  name="id10" /> <br> <br>
        <i><ins>Categorize the destination (max 2): </ins></i>  <br> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id5" value="1" onClick="return KeepCount()" >Christmas<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id6" value="2" onClick="return KeepCount()" >Winter <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id7" value="3" onClick="return KeepCount()" >Summer <br> <br>

        <input type="submit" value="CREATE DESTINATION" /> 


        <br>


        </form>
       <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

function KeepCount() {

var NewCount = 0

if (document.createdest.id5.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

if (document.createdest.id6.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

if (document.createdest.id7.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

if (NewCount == 3)
{
alert('Pick Just Two Please')
document.createdest; return false;
}
} 
</SCRIPT>
```

JSP CODE for inserts :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>create dest code</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <%
    int m[] = new int[5000]; String s[] = new String[5000];        
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
   String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
   Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
   Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  
   boolean check=null!=request.getParameter("id5");
   boolean check1=null!=request.getParameter("id6");
   boolean check2=null!=request.getParameter("id7");
   String id8=request.getParameter("id8");
   String id9=request.getParameter("id9");
   String id10=request.getParameter("id10");
   String sqlString = "INSERT INTO DEST(COUNTRY,CITY,URL) VALUES ('"+id8+"', '"+id9+"','"+id10+"')";
   myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlString);
    myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlString1);
   myStatement.close(); 
   myConnection.close(); %>
    </body>
    <h1 style="color:blue;">Successful Registration </h1>
</html>
```

Comment: Question is not clear sir

Comment: Question isn't clear, and neither are the column names. If you give your key fields better names the solution may become more apparent.

Comment: Why have you added JSP code?  What bearing does this have on your database design?

Comment: i need to make the tables of this and i dont know how the formation of tables can be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to assign a binary value to your checkboxes. So rather than 1,2,3 you could use 1,2,4. Then you would sum the values of the selected boxes and save this unique value.

As in your code:

```
   `input type="checkbox" name="id5" value="1" (...)`
   `input type="checkbox" name="id6" value="2" (...)`
   `input type="checkbox" name="id7" value="4" (...)`
```

The truth table below shows you the different values.

```
id:         ID5   ID6  ID7    Sum
value:       1     2    4  
             x                  1
                   x            2
             x     x            3
                        x       4
             x          x       5
                   x    x       6
```

The solution is not SQL related, but quite frankly, neither is the question...
Good luck!